# How to check stock in C# windows form

Tags: c#, sql

I want to make a notification if in table barang < 0.
This my code:

```
if (cm_status.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Keluar")
   {
       cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Qty FROM Tb_Barang WHERE Nama_Barang = '"+ cm_pilihBarang.SelectedItem.ToString() +"'", conn);
       object S = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       if (S < 0)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("not enough");
       }
       else
       {
           cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Tb_Barang SET Qty=Qty - '" + txt_jumlah.Text + "' WHERE Nama_Barang= '" + cm_pilihBarang.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", conn);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tb_Transaksi VALUES ('" + txt_KodeTransaksi.Text + "', '" + cm_pilihBarang.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', '" + txt_jumlah.Text + "', '" + Datepicker1.Value.Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "', '" + cm_select.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', '" + txt_mengetahui.Text + "', '" + txt_diketahui.Text + "', '" + txt_keterangan.Text + "', '" + cm_status.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' )", conn);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Well, what specific problem are you having?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: You can't compare an object with the value 0. This is a compile time error. You should convert the object to an integer and then execute the check. But consider that if the query doesn't find any record the return is null and you cannot convert a null to an integer. Said that. Look as soon as possible at how to [avoid sql injections](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)